The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge but the working tree is clean
I am trying to merge master branch into release but it is failing with following error:
$ git merge master
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
        UPassConversionLibrary/test/tests/test_decodeAndEncode.cpp
        UPassConversionLibrary/test/tests/test_decodeAndEncode.h
        UPassConversionLibrary/test/tests/test_decodeData.cpp
        UPassConversionLibrary/test/tests/test_decodeData.h
        UPassConversionLibrary/test/tests/test_encodeAndDecode.cpp
        UPassConversionLibrary/test/tests/test_encodeAndDecode.h
        UPassConversionLibrary/test/tests/test_encodeData.cpp
        UPassConversionLibrary/test/tests/test_encodeData.h
Please move or remove them before you merge.
Aborting
Updating 8dc0967..ef198f4

however the working tree is clean:
$ git clean -fxd
$ git status
On branch release
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/release'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean

The files are not ignored:
$ cat .gitignore
*.suo
*.user
x64-Debug
Linux-GCC-Debug
build
install
*.ipch
.vs

The issue is related to renaming the files from camel case to lowercase:
master:
$ find UPassConversionLibrary/test/tests/
UPassConversionLibrary/test/tests/test_decodeAndEncode.cpp
UPassConversionLibrary/test/tests/test_decodeAndEncode.h
UPassConversionLibrary/test/tests/test_decodeData.cpp
UPassConversionLibrary/test/tests/test_decodeData.h
UPassConversionLibrary/test/tests/test_encodeAndDecode.cpp
UPassConversionLibrary/test/tests/test_encodeAndDecode.h
UPassConversionLibrary/test/tests/test_encodeData.cpp
UPassConversionLibrary/test/tests/test_encodeData.h

release:
$ find UPassConversionLibrary/test/tests/
UPassConversionLibrary/test/tests/test_decodeandencode.cpp
UPassConversionLibrary/test/tests/test_decodeandencode.h
UPassConversionLibrary/test/tests/test_decodedata.cpp
UPassConversionLibrary/test/tests/test_decodedata.h
UPassConversionLibrary/test/tests/test_encodeanddecode.cpp
UPassConversionLibrary/test/tests/test_encodeanddecode.h
UPassConversionLibrary/test/tests/test_encodedata.cpp
UPassConversionLibrary/test/tests/test_encodedata.h

This is git bash for Windows. I tried to ignore the case, but had no success:
$ git config --global core.ignorecase true

Do you have any idea how fix this?

cat ~/.gitignore ? git check-ignore -v UPassConversionLibrary/test/tests/test_decodeAndEncode.cpp ?

I found a workaround:

git mv the files to a backup folder
commit
git mv back with a lower case
commit
Than checkout or merge is possible with no error and no conflict.

